# MATLAB + Mex + OpenCV: Links and compiles correctly but can't find library at run time

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I have a `mex` function which uses `OpenCV` that I'm trying to use. The compilation seems to work, but when I try and call the function within `MATLAB` I get this error:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/path/to/project/mexfunction.mexa64': libopencv_legacy.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My `OpenCV 2.4.5` install is located at `/nwdata/username/` (I compiled myself from scratch using the OpenCV recommended settings from their documentation). I compile with mex using this function:

```
function cvmex(mexfile)
    OCV_INC_DIR='/nwdata/username/include/opencv';·
    OCV2_INC_DIR='/nwdata/username/include';·
    OCV_LIB_DIR ='/nwdata/username/lib';·

    mex(mexfile,'-g','-v',['-I',OCV2_INC_DIR],['-I',OCV_INC_DIR],['-L',OCV_LIB_DIR],'DUSE_DOUBLE',...
    '-lopencv_legacy','-lopencv_imgproc','-lopencv_core','-lopencv_contrib','-lopencv_ml',...
    '-lopencv_objdetect','-lopencv_calib3d','-lopencv_flann','-lopencv_features2d',...
    '-lopencv_video','-lopencv_gpu');
end
```

When I compile, I get no errors. I then checked to see what the dependencies of the library are using `ldd mexfunction.mexa64`. Here is the relevant line:

`libopencv_legacy.so.2.4 => /nwdata/username/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4 (0x00002ad6a2123000)`

Ok, so that seems alright. That file definitely exists:

```
[username@machine:/nwdata/username/lib]
$ ls -l libopencv_legacy*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username REDACTED      25 Jul 15 15:07 libopencv_legacy.so -> libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username REDACTED      25 Jul 15 15:07 libopencv_legacy.so.2.4 -> libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username REDACTED 1303944 Jun 17 15:37 libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5


[username@machine:/nwdata/username/lib]
$ file libopencv_legacy.so*
libopencv_legacy.so:       symbolic link to `libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5'
libopencv_legacy.so.2.4:   symbolic link to `libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5'
libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Running on Linux:

`Linux machine@redacted 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 4 20:33:44 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`MATLAB R2011b, and g++ 4.6.3.`

This seems odd. Any ideas? This machine is part of a cluster, so I don't have root access or anything.

Comment: check the path and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment

Comment: The directory is not on my shell or MATLAB path. Here is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`>> getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')`
    `ans =

    /usr/local/matlab2011b/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab2011b/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab2011b/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab2011b/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab2011b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/matlab2011b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/matlab2011b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64`

Comment: can you add it to the ld lib path?

Comment: I did this:

`p = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'); p=[p,':/nwdata/username/lib']; setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',p);`

Checked it again and it's the last item on the path. Same thing, still doesn't work even after a recompile. Also did an `addpath('/nwdata/username/lib')` and it's still no good.

Comment: you could also use `LD_PRELOAD` by invoking `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/lib.so matlab` to start MATLAB. Unrelated: checkout the [`mexopencv`](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) project

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem some days ago. This problem only happens when you using the matlab remotely on a cluster. Editing the LD_LIBRARY_FILE in Matlab is useless, and I don't know why. I solved the problem by defining the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bashrc (or .bash_profile).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and solved it by adding a soft link to the missing library in the Matlab binaries directory, where all the other libs were located, in my case:

```
sudo ln -s /users/marc/lib/libName.so /opt/matlab/MATLAB_R2014b_Linux_x86-64/bin/glnxa64/libName.so
```

solved the problem.