# Error creating LMDB database file in MATLAB for Caffe

Tags: image, matlab, shell, caffe, lmdb

I am trying to convert a dataset of images to LMDB format for use with Caffe, and I need to call the convert_imageset function for applying this conversion from inside Matlab.

I am using Linux, and I have created a shell (.sh) script with the needed parameters for running the conversion. Here is an example of how does my shell file look like:

```
GLOG_logtostderr=1 /usr/local/caffe-master2/build/tools/convert_imageset -resize_height=256 -resize_width=256 images_folder data_split/train.txt data_split/dataCNN_train_lmdb
```

When I simply run my script from the terminal like this:

```
./example_shell.sh
```

it works without any problem. 
But when I try to do it from Matlab using the `system()` function:

```
system('./example_shell.sh')
```

it seems it is not able to open/find my files, rising the following error for each image in train.txt:

```
I0917 18:15:13.637830 8605 convert_imageset.cpp:82] A total of 68175 images.
I0917 18:15:13.638947 8605 db.cpp:34] Opened lmdb data_split/dataCNN_train_lmdb
E0917 18:15:13.639143 8605 io.cpp:77] Could not open or find file ...
E0917 18:15:13.639143 8605 io.cpp:77] Could not open or find file ...
E0917 18:15:13.639143 8605 io.cpp:77] Could not open or find file ...
```

Here are some sample lines from train.txt file (do not mind the 0s, they are just dummy labels):

```
/media/user/HDD_2TB/Food_101_Dataset/images/beef_carpaccio/970563.jpg 0
/media/user/HDD_2TB/Food_101_Dataset/images/chocolate_mousse/1908117.jpg 0
/media/user/HDD_2TB/Food_101_Dataset/images/cup_cakes/632892.jpg 0
/media/user/HDD_2TB/Food_101_Dataset/images/garlic_bread/1498092.jpg 0
/media/user/HDD_2TB/Food_101_Dataset/images/ceviche/3115634.jpg 0
```

They are absolute paths, so there should be no problem.

Any idea you might have about what could be happening can be very helpful for me!

Thank you,

Marc

Comment: what is the working directory in matlab? what is the working directory when you run `./example_shell.sh`? it seems like relative paths are different and therefore you are unable to locate files.

Comment: I am testing it from the same working path, so that can't be the problem. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I would try and add an explicit `cd` command at the first line of `example_shell.sh` that puts you explicitly in the directory you should be in.

Comment: Same result with the `cd` command.

Comment: Can you please post a few lines from `data_split/train.txt` file? are the paths there relative or absolute?

Comment: Ok course! :) I just updated the main post.

Comment: it seems like your images are located on a mounded device. is it possible it is not accessible by Matlab for some reason?  can you open any of the images in matlab using a simple `imread`? can you change the `images_folder` in `example_shell.sh` to `/`? is it possible some of the paths contain symbolic links?

Comment: There are no symbolic links anywhere along the path, and Matlab has no problem reading any of the images in those folders.

Comment: My guess is that maybe it is some problem about file permissions instead of paths. The thing is that I have granted all permissions (rw and even x) to the images but there is still no change.

Comment: have you granted `rx` permissions to the folders as well?

Comment: another possibility is that for some reason caffe in matlab's shell is unable to run opencv routines. can you check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on your terminal and in matlab? The error is emitted from [this part of the code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/util/io.cpp#L80).

Comment: Indeed, the folders have full permissions as well.

Checking the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I have this on my terminal:
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
And a lot more paths in Matlab:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

Comment: I don't think it's a CUDA related issue, but **opencv** related. can you check for any opencv related folders in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in both terminal and matlab?

Comment: might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647403/matlab-mex-opencv-links-and-compiles-correctly-but-cant-find-library-at-ru

Comment: Those are all the paths I have in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. What I suppose that means that Caffe probably is not using any of those for accessing OpenCV, it must have the link somewhere else.

Although, by now I have managed to do a **weird** workaround for it to work. I am calling my Matlab program from Python and checking whenever it needs to call the `./example_shell.sh`. In that case Python is in charge of doing the conversion and then the Matlab execution continues...

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to solve the specific problem with Matlab, but I have managed to do the following (weird) workaround by using .txt files for communication:

1. Call the main Matlab's program from Python.
2. Check whenever Matlab needs to call the `./example_shell.sh` script.
3. Python does the conversion calling `./example_shell.sh`.
4. Matlab execution continues.